# How to add style for every listbox.Item in code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, listboxitem

i am trying to add different styles for every listbox.Item in my project. Can anyone help me about that?

`

```
            foreach (var item in orderList)
            {
                var itm = new ListBoxItem();

                if (item.CustomOrder)
                {
                    itm.Content = item;
                    itm.Style = customOrderStyle;
                    listbox.Items.Add(itm);


                }
                else
                {
                    itm.Content = item;
                    itm.Style = newOrderStyle;
                    listbox.Items.Add(itm);


                }
            }
```

`

[image: My content doesnt shown like this.]

I know that i am adding Listbox item to the listbox, that's why content is doesnt shown.
I try some different things too but still dont know how to solve it.

Comment: Do you want a different style for all 4 elements in the UI? Or a different style when `item.CustomOrder == true` ?

Comment: It's better, of course, to do this in XAML using a style selector or a template, but I don't see an error in your code. Explain in more detail what is wrong with the output? Should he be different? If so, which one?

Comment: You have to use DataTemplate instead of a Style. [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: @ShaiCohen I want different style for all elements. As example if order is custom it has to be a different style. But if its normal it has to be normal style.

Comment: @EldHasp Data has to be shown must be different for custom Orders. So i am using ListboxItem style and binding items with data binding.

Comment: @BionicCode I am already doing that but, i do it in my listbox Item styles because it has to be different for every order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of a more typical for WPF implementation:

```cs
namespace Core2022.SO.Ali.ListBoxItemStyleSelector
{
    public class OrderItem
    {
        public bool CustomOrder { get; set; }

        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Core2022.SO.Ali.ListBoxItemStyleSelector
{
    public class OrderViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<OrderItem> Orders { get; } = new ObservableCollection<OrderItem>();

        public OrderViewModel()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Orders.Add(new OrderItem() { Id = i, CustomOrder = i % 2 == 0 });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Core2022.SO.Ali.ListBoxItemStyleSelector
{
    public class CustomOrderStyleSelector : StyleSelector
    {
        public Style? CustomOrderTrue { get; set; }
        public Style? CustomOrderFalse { get; set; }

        public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            if (item is OrderItem order)
            {
                return (order.CustomOrder ? CustomOrderTrue : CustomOrderFalse)
                    ?? throw new NullReferenceException(); ;
            }
            return base.SelectStyle(item, container);
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<Window x:Class="Core2022.SO.Ali.ListBoxItemStyleSelector.OrdersWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2022.SO.Ali.ListBoxItemStyleSelector"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="OrdersWindow" Height="300" Width="200"
        DataContext="{DynamicResource vm}">
    <FrameworkElement.Resources>
        <local:OrderViewModel x:Key="vm"/>
        <local:CustomOrderStyleSelector x:Key="customOrderStyleSelector">
            <local:CustomOrderStyleSelector.CustomOrderTrue>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
                </Style>
            </local:CustomOrderStyleSelector.CustomOrderTrue>
            <local:CustomOrderStyleSelector.CustomOrderFalse>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Coral"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style>
            </local:CustomOrderStyleSelector.CustomOrderFalse>
        </local:CustomOrderStyleSelector>
    </FrameworkElement.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}"
                 DisplayMemberPath="Id"
                 ItemContainerStyleSelector="{DynamicResource customOrderStyleSelector}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) link and go to the "Creating the DataTemplate as a Resource" section (and read the next section too). It shows how to define a `DataTemplate` as a resource and how to use the `DataTemplate.DataType` property. Just don't give the template a `x:Key` so that WPF can pick the proper template based on the item type automatically.

Then define a data model for each individual looking item and stop what you are doing: don't create `ListBoxItem` explicitly (let WPF do it via the `DataTemplate`). And instead of checking for the `CustomOrder` property, introduce related model classes e.g. `DefaultOrder` and `CustomOrder`.  Then add items of those types to a common source collection that you bind to your `ListBox`:

**IOrder.cs**

```cs
interface IOrder
{
  ...
}
```

**DefaultOrder.cs**

```cs
class DefaultOrder : IOrder
{
  ...
}
```

**CustomOrder.cs**

```cs
class CustomOrder : IOrder
{
  ...
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <ListBox x:Name="OrdersOverview">
    <ListBox.Resources>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DefaultOrder}">
        ...
      </DataTemplate>

      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CustomOrder}">
        ...
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>
  </ListBox>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
prtial class MainWindow : Window
{
  private ObservableCollection<IOrder> Orders { get; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Orders = new ObservableCollection<IOrder>();
    this.OrdersOverview.ItemsSource = this.Orders;
  }

  private void CreateDefaultOrder()
  {
    var newOrder = new DefaultOrder();

    // Show the new order in the ListBox
    this.Orders.Add(newOrder);
  }


  private void CreateCustomOrder()
  {
    var newOrder = new CustomOrder();

    // Show the new order in the ListBox
    this.Orders.Add(newOrder);
  }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't using different orders there is a bool section in order entity, but it will work for different section of my project thanks for sharing, it will help a lot. :)

Comment: I know you are using a bool. I was suggesting a better design that also enables extensibility and reduces code. I recommend to redesign your classes. It's generally better to introduce a new data type for type variations e.g. regarding behavior or attributes. Using boolean flags to control the behavior of a type is generally a bad idea. If you have different type of orders you should introduce different data types and not flags or enums. Anyway, good luck with your project!

Comment: Oh i understand it now. I will definitely create my entities in this way on my new projects. Thanks again, you instruct me a lot.